# rv-each-*: removes last item in view while removing 1st item in model

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

I've got some items in my model

```
model.items = [
    {
        index: 1,
        data: "data-1"
    },
    {
        index: 2,
        data: "data-2"
    },
    {
        index: 3,
        data: "data-3"
    },

];
```

and use rv-each-* to iterate them in my view.

```
<p rv-each-item="items" rv-data="item.data">
    {item.index}
</p>
```

Now I want to delete first item. So I use `Array.shift()` method and it removes first item in  model - But it removes 3rd item in DOM.

http://jsfiddle.net/H3bDT/11/

Is there a way to remove 1st item in DOM either?